# Adding a loop to a displayed menu so that it is displayed repeatedly until the last option is selected and stop the loop

Tags: java, menu, switch-statement, display

I have created a display menu and want to add a loop to continuously display the menu until the last option is selected. Not sure if I am doing it right.

Let me know if there is anywhere I can add on thanks!

```
   import java.util.Scanner;

   public class loopTest
   {    
      public void displayMenu()
       {
         System.out.println("A. Option #A");
         System.out.println("B. Option #B");
         System.out.println("C. Option #C");
         System.out.println("D. Option #D");
         System.out.println("X. Exit");
         System.out.println("Please enter your choice: ");
   }

   public void start()
   {
      Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
      String s = "";

      while(s < size())
        {
          displayMenu();
          console.nextLine();
          switch (s.charAt(0))
           {
            case 'A': System.out.println("A. Option #A"); break;
            case 'B': System.out.println("B. Option #B"); break;
            case 'C': System.out.println("C. Option #C"); break;
            case 'D': System.out.println("D. Option #D"); break;
            case 'X': System.out.println("X. Exit"); break;
            default: System.out.println("Error, please enter a valid 
                                        character");
           }
       }
       s++;
      }
     }
```

Comment: Two problems immediately evident: 1) `size()` isn't defined anywhere, so the code won't even compile successfully; 2) `s` is obviously meant to receive the user's input command, but nothing ever reads any input into `s` (maybe `console.nextLine()` should have been `s = console.nextLine()`?)

Comment: thank you for pointing out. it works now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

consider using a boolean variable

```
boolean wantToExit = false;
while (!wantToExit ) {

   ....  // switch
   case 'X': 
         wantToExit = true;
         System.out.println("X. Exit"); 
         break;
}
```

**note**

`s` is a string, there is no `<` comparator nor `s++` incrementor
Also, you are not assign a value to `s` from the `Console` input